# How to fix the error about supertype when implementing a method with parameter E e?

Tags: java, stack, supertype

I need to create an array-based stack that gets the method from an interface. There I want to implement the *push(E e)* method from the interface, but I am getting following error:

```
The method push(E) of type ArrayStack<E> must override or implement a supertype method
```

```
public interface Stack<E> extends BasicCollection {

   public E top() throws EmptyStackException;

   public void push(E e);

   public E pop() throws EmptyStackException;

}
```

```
@Override
   public void push(E e) {
       if(size == arrayCapacity) {
           array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length * 2);
       }
       array[size] = e;
       size += 1;
   }
```

How can I solve this? It has the same parameter as in the interface. What is wrong?

Comment: Show the class declaration where you state the interface you implement. You might be doing it wrong.

Comment: public class ArrayStack<E> implements Stack

Comment: Should be `implements Stack<E>`

Comment: See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: thank you @khelwood, it worked with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `implements Stack` you are using a raw type.

See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Because you haven't specified the generic type `E` in `Stack<E>`, the base type Object is used, as if you wrote `implements Stack<Object>`. That means that the class is expected to implement the method `push(Object)` instead of `push(E)`.

Presumably you meant

```
class ArrayStack<E> implements Stack<E>
```

Answer (score 0):

public class ArrayStack implements Stack

This was my class declaration. This one worked:

public class ArrayStack implements Stack

Just added  to the Stack of the clas declaration.